# Re-indexing CSV file by variable

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So, I have a CSV file as so: [smaller sample]

```
value,variable,comparison
260,5,0
266,5,0
272,6,0
418,7,1
416,7,1
260,1,0
320,1,0
558,1,0
306,2,0
568,2,0
544,2,0
310,3,0
558,3,0
446,3,0
262,4,0
394,4,0
```

Essentially, what needs to happen is the column `variable` needs to be re-indexed, so instead of being ordered in the current index `5,6,7,1,2,4` it needs to be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7` **without** being sorted. The position of the data needs to be retained. Not sure how to do this, will answer any questions anybody has. I've thought about maybe using the pandas library, or splitting the CSV file into multiple dictionaries, and then changing the key to 1,2,3,4,5, etc.

Currently, to get the current output I've used the stacking function in pandas, then outputted to CSV. Here's my code:

```
    index_column_name ='value'
    dt = dataset.iloc[:,9:16].stack().sort_index(level=1).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).to_frame()
    #Create the "index_value" column
    dt['variable'] = pandas.Categorical(dt.index).codes+1
    dt.rename(columns={0:index_column_name}, inplace=True)
    dt.set_index(index_column_name, inplace=True)
    dt.to_csv(filename + ".csv", sep=',')
```

Desired output:

```
260,1,0
266,1,0
272,2,0
418,3,1
416,3,1
260,4,0
320,4,0
558,4,0
306,5,0
568,5,0
544,5,0
310,6,0
558,6,0
446,6,0
262,7,0
394,7,0
```

Again, I need the actual position of the data to be the same, so instead of using a sorting function, the different groups of `variable` need to be in the same place.

Comment: `df['variable'] = np.sort(df['variable'])`?

Comment: Worked, thanks if you want to put this as an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: how come it worked in the way you described ? just tried,  for example np.sort(df['variable']) will keep the number of 1s but this is not happening in your desired output

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
reordering_map = {old_value: new_value for old_value, new_value in zip(df.variable.unique(), range(1, len(df.variable.unique()) + 1) )}

print(reordering_map)
# output: {5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 7}

df.variable = df.variable.apply(lambda x: reordering_map[x])

df
```

[image]